# How to properly add new hard drives to Debian Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, format

I’ve added 2x 2TB hard drives and unlike windows where I would see a C:/ D:/ etc… I see nothing

So my question is how can I format these drives and where would I see them (I use Swish to view them Windows 7)

This is what I get after using `fdisk -l`:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdc: 150.0 GB, 150038863360 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 18241 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00055c68

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *           1       17498   140546048   83  Linux
/dev/sdc2           17498       18242     5974017    5  Extended
/dev/sdc5           17498       18242     5974016   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the parted tool instead of fdisk to partition these.

http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/Running-Parted.html#Running-Parted

You can also use gparted if you are running a GUI such as Gnome or KDE.

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

Either way you'll need to mount the drives once you have them partitioned.  Unlike Windows, the Linux filesystem is all one tree, so first you need to decide where you want to put these disks in the tree.  (For example, I have a /data directory where I mount the drive I used to store my personal data.)  You can use the mount command to mount the drives but they won't be mounted automatically at boot time unless you list them in the /etc/fstab file.

Answer (score 0):

Just format the whole disk and mount them somewhere.

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb
mount /dev/sdb /var/www
```

Etc…

To make mount permanent, add the line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb /var/www ext3 defaults
```

There are many variations and you should look up more information and understand different filesystems etc… to be sure that is what you want.